# How to substitute place holders in a string with values

Tags: c#, regex

Given the string

```
string command = "%ans[1]%*100/%ans[0]%"
```

Will replace to
%ans[1]% to array[1]
%ans[0]% to array[2]

How do I substitute the place holders in `command` with the values in the array to get the following result? Should I use Regular Expressions for this?

And using Regex.Replace ?

```
"test2*100/test1"
```

Comment: elaborate your question - try to state the problem more clearly

Comment: Why am I not surprised that this question from an obviously non-native english speaker has been voted to close 3 times rather than attempting to clarify the question. This site gets worse every day.  To the asker, your question is incredibly unclear. Please try to rephrase or provide a code sample to get more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a standard *Replace*.

Something like

```
string command = "%ans[1]%*100/%ans[0]%";
string[] array = new string[] { "test1", "test2" };
for (int iReplace = 0; iReplace < array.Length; iReplace++)
    command = command.Replace(String.Format("%ans[{0}]%", iReplace), array[iReplace]);
```

Comment: Wow, that's kinda freaky. Well, not really I guess.

Comment: You can definitely use Regex.Replace, but it's a lot more heavy handed for such a simple problem. Regex is definitely not *needed* here. This is a simple, easy to understand, and working (or so it seems :) ) solution.

Comment: if you can use Regex.Replace it improve in my knowleage base :)

Answer (score 3):

You could just use string.Format to insert your string into the command string:

```
string command = "{0}*100/{1}";

string[] array = new string[] { "test1", "test2" };

string.Format(command, array[1], array[0]);
```

Comment: And what if the format of `command` cannot be changed? (I don't know if this is the case; maybe @monkey_boys can clarify.)

Comment: String For mat must give fixed agument not dynamic string for used

Comment: I agree with you, i only thought that's what he intended to do.

Comment: The question of @monkey_boys was very unclear when he posted the question. After looking at another thread he posted after, @astander clearly have a better answer for him.

Answer (score 1):

This does it, but I doubt it's what your looking for. Oh well.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    command = command.Replace(string.Format("%ans[{0}]%", i), array[i]);
}
```